# Losing scope when using ng-include

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-include

I have this module routes:

```
var mainModule = angular.module('lpConnect', []).
    config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {template:'views/home.html', controller:HomeCtrl}).
        when('/admin', {template:'views/admin.html', controller:AdminCtrl}).
        otherwise({redirectTo:'/connect'});
}]);
```

Home HTML:

```
<div ng-include src="views.partial1"></div>
```

`partial1` HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="addLine()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="lineText" size="30" placeholder="Type your message here">
</form>
```

`HomeCtrl`:

```
function HomeCtrl($scope, $location, $window, $http, Common) {
    ...
    $scope.views = {
        partial1:"views/partial1.html"
    };

    $scope.addLine = function () {
        $scope.chat.addLine($scope.lineText);
        $scope.lines.push({text:$scope.lineText});
        $scope.lineText = "";
    };
...
}
```

In the `addLine` function `$scope.lineText` is `undefined`, this can be resolved by adding `ng-controller="HomeCtrl"` to `partial1.html`, however it causes the controller to be called twice. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This is because of `ng-include` which creates a new child scope, so `$scope.lineText` isn’t changed. I think that `this` refers to the current scope, so `this.lineText` should be set.

Answer (score 259):

As @Renan mentioned, ng-include creates a new child scope.  This scope prototypically inherits (see dashed lines below) from the HomeCtrl scope.  `ng-model="lineText"` actually creates a primitive scope property on the child scope, not HomeCtrl's scope.  This child scope is not accessible to the parent/HomeCtrl scope:

[image: ng-include scope]

To store what the user typed into HomeCtrl's $scope.lines array, I suggest you pass the value to the addLine function:

```
 <form ng-submit="addLine(lineText)">
```

In addition, since lineText is owned by the ngInclude scope/partial, I feel it should be responsible for clearing it:

```
 <form ng-submit="addLine(lineText); lineText=''">
```

Function addLine() would thus become:

```
$scope.addLine = function(lineText) {
    $scope.chat.addLine(lineText);
    $scope.lines.push({
        text: lineText
    });
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/9krVn/).

Alternatives:

- define an object property on HomeCtrl's $scope, and use that in the partial: `ng-model="someObj.lineText`; [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/9krVn/4/)
- not recommended, this is more of a hack: use $parent in the partial to create/access a `lineText` property on the HomeCtrl $scope:  `ng-model="$parent.lineText"`; [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/9krVn/3/)

It is a bit involved to explain why the above two alternatives work, but it is fully explained here: [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

I don't recommend using `this` in the addLine() function.  It becomes much less clear which scope is being accessed/manipulated.

Comment: I used **objects**, but they scope was still masked.  I tried `$parent.` and it worked great.  Why do you consider it a hack?  (I can see it would add maintenance if you refactored your html)

Comment: Same question @Jess had , why is this considered a hack ?

Comment: @qbert65536, it is essentially a hack/fragile because if you restructure your HTML, it might not work anymore.  E.g., you might then need to use `$parent.$parent...` to get it to work.  Put another way, using `$parent` makes assumptions about the DOM structure.

Comment: @Jess' link above has been changed to this __[Understanding Scopes ngInclude](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-include)__. Read the whole page, it's great.

Comment: Thank you for this. I think this should be the accepted answer. Using `this` feels like a hack in Angular terms

Comment: I has going crazy about this. Thank for the detailed explanation @MarkRajcok! +1

Comment: This is a great detailed answer, but I tried all of them without any success. I have a form with some input to a controller and the result of a controller should be viewed on another div. Once I enter any input the synchronicity will be lost and I will have a constant 0.00 value on the view div while the app is running.

Answer (score 35):

Instead of using `this` as the accepted answer suggests, use `$parent` instead. So in your `partial1.html`you'll have:

```
<form ng-submit="$parent.addLine()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.lineText" size="30" placeholder="Type your message here">
</form>
```

If you want to learn more about the scope in `ng-include` or other directives, check this out: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-include

Comment: For any reader, he means  `$scope.$parent` instead of `$parent` is undefined according to Angular.

Comment: This answer saves the day for me! Thanks so much for pointing out the use of $parent.

Comment: is $scope.$parent pass by reference? or it's just a copy of parent?

Comment: @Sebastiallonso is wrong. $scope.$parent.lineText is undefined. $parent.lineText is working, this.lineText or simply just lineText are also working

Comment: Its `$scope.$parent` that works for me in angular 1.3.20

Comment: @Sebastialonso is right and so is OMGPOP: in the directive or html $scope.$parent is $parent if you are referring to it inside a controller it is $scope (or in a directive typically 'scope').$parent... Inside html $scope is already passed so it would make it look like $parent is right but officially it is $scope.$parent

Answer (score 4):

I've figured out how to work around this issue without mixing parent and sub scope data.
Set a `ng-if` on the the `ng-include` element and set it to a scope variable.
For example :

```
<div ng-include="{{ template }}" ng-if="show"/>
```

In your controller, when you have set all the data you need in your sub scope, then set show to `true`. The `ng-include` will copy at this moment the data set in your scope and set it in your sub scope.

The rule of thumb is to reduce scope data deeper the scope are, else you have this situation.

Max

Comment: I'm using this approach for a similar issue but it's not proper for all cases. Especially when you want the included element to never get hidden...