# AngularJS: Include and scope inheritance = broken bindings?

Tags: angularjs

In an attempt to clean up my partials I recently moved some of my global menus into seperate templates which I now include in the views which need them. As the menu (including a search bar) is global I have created a service which keeps track of the state of the menu and so on.

Problem is something funny happened after I started including.

**HTML (Jade) of the View**

```
div(ng-controller='HeroUnitCtrl', ng-include src='heroTemplate')
div(ng-controller='MainSearchBarCtrl', ng-include src='searchBarTemplate')

div.row-fluid
    div.span12
        table.table.table-striped.table-bordered
            tr
                th
                    a(ng-click='setOrder("id")') ID#
                th
                    a(ng-click='setOrder("client.name")') Kunde
                th
                    a(ng-click='setOrder("technician.name")') Tekniker
                th
                    a(ng-click='setOrder("createdAt")') Opprettet
                th
                    a(ng-click='setOrder("statusString")') Status

            tr(ng-repeat='record in records | orderBy:orderProp | filter:searchBar')
                td
                    a(ng-href='#/records/show/{{record.id}}') {{record.id}}
                td {{record.client.name}}
                td {{record.technician.name}}
                td {{record.createdAt}}
                td {{record.statusString}}
```

**HTML (Jade) searchBarTemplate**

```
input#searchField.input-xxlarge(type='text', placeholder='placeholder', ng-change='searchBarUpdated()', ng-model='searchBar')
```

*Now to the bit I really don't understand,*

**MainSearchBarCtrl**

```
function MainSearchBarCtrl(MainSearchBarService, $scope, $location) {
    $scope.searchBarTemplate = 'partials/main-searchbar';
    $scope.searchBar = 'Hello World!';

    $scope.searchBarUpdated = function() {
        console.log('Search bar update: ' + $scope.searchBar);
        MainSearchBarService.searchBarUpdated($scope.searchBar);
    }   
}
```

Initially the value of *searchBar* is as expected "Hello World". However, if I append any text it still only prints "Hello World". Or, if I replace the text it prints undefined. So it seems the binding is broken, but I don't really see why this is happening. Worth mentioning is that this wasn't case before I moved my search bar into a separate template.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: Alright, I'll get a fiddle up. If you look at the top of the view it includes searchBarTemplate.

Comment: I modified comment about scope... but hard to help without seeing a live version

Comment: Heh, okay. Here is the live version running on Heroku, http://katana-kvds.herokuapp.com/#/

Comment: ng-include creates a new child scope.  So in your searchBarTemplate, using `ng-model="searchBar"` results in a new `searchBar` property being created on the child scope, which hides/shadows the parent `searchBar` property of the same name.  Try using `$scope.obj = {searchBar: 'Hello World!}` in your controller, and `ng-model="obj.searchBar"` in your template.

Comment: @MarkRajcok nailed problem, in future easier to put demos in **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b:angularjs@1.1.x+starter-angularjs?p=preview)** so they can be edited and much easier to review code. Allows for really simple creation of external files for partials and different js files etc

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I wasn't aware of Plunker, so thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, `ng-include` creates a new child scope. So in your searchBarTemplate, using `ng-model="searchBar"` results in a new `searchBar` property being created on the child scope, which hides/shadows the parent `searchBar` property of the same name.

In the controller, define an object:

```
$scope.obj = {searchBar: 'Hello World!};
```

And then use

```
ng-model="obj.searchBar"
```

in your template.  When objects are used (instead of primitives), the child scope does not create a new property.  Rather, due to the way [JavaScript prototypal inheritance works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482), the child scope will find the property on the parent scope.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/14146317/215945 which has a picture showing the child and parent scopes and how the child property hides/shadows the parent property if a primitive is used.

Note that using `$parent` is another option, but it is not "best practice".

Comment: Just a quick follow-up. Is it possible to access the child scope from the parent scope? I'm guessing not due to the inheritance, but.

Comment: No... well yes, but you'd have to use Angular private $$ variables like ``$$childHead`` and such.  I would not recommend doing that (ever).

Comment: Does this look the same with the controllerAs syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Try using $parent instead of $scope in your included template

Comment: That's a bad idea I think. Move your code into a partial view, or inside a directive, or both, and your code isn't working anymore. And to make it work  you'll have to use $parent.$parent....

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-include