# Angular - ngModel not updating when called inside ngInclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

First and foremost, the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/v1uTz5

This is a working demo of the issue I am running into.

I have a `ng-include` to include a partial.

Inside the partial I have an text input with `ngModel` AND directive.

The model updates accordingly inside the include, but any interaction outside the include is ignored.  The `{{test}}` outside the include doesn't update, but the `{{test}}` inside does.

The directive, when called, handles the `enter` key and calls the correct scope and function.  However, the `$scope.test` variable has never been updated, but `$scope.testFinal` is updated and the `ng-include` template renders it appropriately.  Trying to reset the `$scope.test` model does not work either.

Am I missing something here?  Or is this a bug with the directive or with the `ng-include`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412410/angularjs-losing-scope-when-using-ng-include

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Instead of using a primitiive to define the variable, make it an object.

```
$scope.model={test:''};
```

Directives create their own scope for each item. When you equate a primitive to a new scope variable, it has no binding to the original, however when original is an object, a reference is created , not a copy, and changes made in one will reflect in the other

Simple explanatory example:

```
var a ='foo';
var b= a;
/* now change a*/
a='bar';
alert( b) // is still 'foo'
```

now do the same with object:

```
var obj_1= {a:'foo'};
var obj_2=obj_1;
/* now change obj_1.a*/
obj_1.a='bar';
alert( obj_2.a) // change to obj_1 will also change obj_2 and alert returns "bar"*/
```

[Your Plunker Modified](http://plnkr.co/edit/1PVHZ1?p=preview)

[Read this article on angular wiki for more detailed explanation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance)

Comment: Very simple, and I knew this all along, but I never understood the reason.  Thanks for the article.  It should definitely get more rep on their site.

Comment: Thanks, you saved several my hours.

Comment: The angular wiki link is no longer valid.

Comment: This is the only solution that actually worked for me. Using this.varName or $parent.varName does nothing. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

John Lindquist has a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTx23w4z6Kc&list=PLP6DbQBkn9ymGQh2qpk9ImLHdSH5T7yw7) about it. Although he doesn't quite explains why you need to use an object.

Basically every time there is a new non-isolated scope, every property of the parent scope is copied to the new scope and, as @charlietfl explained, copying a primitive type **really** creates a "copy" but with objects what you get is a reference, hence the changes are *global*.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-include` creates its own scope and it is different than outer scope. Use `this.test` instead of `$scope.test` inside `ng-include` template. It will work properly.