# Form not working when inserted with ng-include

Tags: angularjs

I have a form that is inserted via `ng-include`, but it doesn't work. If I manually paste in the html template from the `ng-include` src (instead of using `ng-include`), then it works fine. Is there something about `ng-include` that disables forms?

```
<div ng-include src="'views/login_form.html'"></div>
```

login_form.html:

```
<form ng-submit="loginUser()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="login_input_field v_align_top">
                <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="email">
            </td>
            <td class="login_input_field">
                <input type="password" name="pass" ng-model="password">
            </td>
            <td class="login_button_container">
                <button type="submit" id="login" name="login">Login</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're probably seeing the same problem as described here: [AngularJS - losing scope when using ng-include][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11417113/584846

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking out the loginUser() into its own subcontroller.

That way your function will be in the same `$scope`.

```
<div ng-controller="LoginUserController">
  <div ng-include src="'views/login_form.html'"></div>
</div>
```