# AngularJS - ng-include ng-controller and scope not binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following main view

```
<div ng-include="'otions.html'"></div>
```

and options.html has the following

```
<div ng-controller="OptionsController">Options</div>
<input type="text" ng-model="keyword" value="{{keyword}}" />
<button ng-click="search()">Search</button>
```

But "keyword" is not binding to the scope in OptionsController.

```
app.controller('OptionsController', 
              ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.keyword = "all";
  $scope.search = function() {
    console.log("hello")
  };

}]);
```

when I click on the button, I don't see `hello` and the keyword `all` doesn't appear in the input text.

I tried moving the ng-controller part as follows

```
<div ng-controller="OptionsController" ng-include="'otions.html'"></div>
```

And things work as expected.

I read through the answers in [AngularJS - losing scope when using ng-include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412410/angularjs-losing-scope-when-using-ng-include) - and I *think* my problem is related, but just need some more explanation to undertstand what's going on.

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo here but also in your source: the file you're including is references as `otions.html` instead of `options.html`

Comment: In your source you specify ng-controller for the first `div` only, so your input and button are not in the scope of your controller. Probably it is a typo. If not then it could be a reason.

Answer (score 7):

You should write options.html like this:

```
<div ng-controller="OptionsController">Options
<input type="text" ng-model="keyword" value="{{keyword}}" />
<button ng-click="search()">Search</button>
</div>
```

OptionsController should be put in the outer html element.

Comment: Good catch, I missed that.  In the original html the input it outside of the div marked with the controller so the scope variable doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

i have face same problem,

Under main tag it will be work fine but, When bind some data to nav.html it not work.

find this link

[AngularJS - losing scope when using ng-include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412410/angularjs-losing-scope-when-using-ng-include)

inside include its work child scope.
better option to create custom directive its easy solution