# AngularJs validate whole model

Tags: angularjs

I have a view with some inputs in a table row. Is there a way to check if the whole model is valid without using form (can't have form in tr ) ?

```
<tr ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
    <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="someModel.name" required="required" ng-minlength="3">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="someModel.x" required="required" ng-minlength="3">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="someModel.y" required="required" ng-minlength="3">
    </td>
    <td>
        <button ng-click="save(someModel)">Save</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In controller i want to have something like this

```
function ($rootScope, $scope, serive) {
    $scope.save = function (someModel) {
        if (someModel.$valid) {}
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a form and it has a name, it automatically can give you exactly what you required.

```
<form name="someForm">
    <tr ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="someModel.name" data-ng-required="true" ng-minlength="3">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="someModel.x" data-ng-required="true" ng-minlength="3">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="someModel.y" data-ng-required="true" ng-minlength="3">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button data-ng-disabled="!someForm.$valid" ng-click="someForm.$valid && Namesave(someModel)">Save</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Otherwise, there is no automagical way to do that. I guess you can write a directive which gives you all your inputs and their validators, parse them, and have a validation on the whole model, but no such thing readily exists, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to do it:

- [ng-form name="myForm"](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm) can be used to avoid using  tag and it should work - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hbJJ6txbyW9IHwa4yc8X?p=preview).
- but using ng-include will make the form unavailable to controller - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cG6L353WVyc27zKUSYY3?p=preview) , [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412410/angularjs-losing-scope-when-using-ng-include). A work around for this issue is to pass the form as parameter to the controller method - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tGRosdC3s5Q4Tj8AQ7P6?p=preview)