# $scope not updating inside ng-include (no parent variables being used)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am `ng-include`-ing a nav bar with a controller called `NavCtrl` which has a logout button that listens to a `logout` function and a `logoutError` field.

Both `logout` and `logoutError` are used only inside the template partial (`nav.html`). The partial doesn't use any scope variables from the parent or vice-versa.

The `logout` function works just fine on click, but the `logoutError` doesn't update to reflect a invalid logout response from the server. The scope variables work just fine on load, they just dont update the second time.

I cannot figure out why this is happening.

Code here:

`nav.html`

```
<div ng-controller="NavCtrl">
  <!-- Nav Bar Stuff -->
          <li><a href="#" ng-click="logout()" ng-hide="logoutRequestInProgress">Logout</a></li>
  <!-- More Nav Bar Stuff -->

  <!-- logoutError here doesn't update, but loads correctly when the page is first rendered -->
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" ng-show="logoutError">
    <strong>Logout Failed!</strong> {{ logoutError }} 
  </div>
</div>
```

`nav.js`

```
'use strict';

app.controller('NavCtrl', function ($scope, $window, $location, AuthService) {
  if ($window.localStorage.token) {
    $scope.logout = function () {    
      // Reset error vars
      $scope.logoutError = null;
      AuthService.logout().then(function() {
        // success stuff 
      }, function (response) {
        // !!! THIS UPDATE DOESNT WORK !!!
        $scope.logoutError = 'Server Error';
      });
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412410/angularjs-losing-scope-when-using-ng-include

Comment: Thanks, I did read it but that question is trying to use a variable in the child scope from the parent scope. Its not what I am asking here.

Comment: Do you find a solution? I'm facing a similar problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not. :( Please reply to this if you find a solution.