# ng-model not updating on ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Firstly, here is the [**plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/5jigj5WMz14icuh5THBK).

I has this template working when it was in a single page. But when I tried splitting it up using the `ng-include`. Suddenly the ng-model stopped updating.

I'm just a beginner in AngularJS.

I'm adding some conditional classes based on the checkbox Boolean value. But right now it's not working.

Did check the [**docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude). But that's seriously not clear for me.

Please let me know on what should I do to update the `ng-model` when ever I use the `ng-include`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14146317/3191896

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - losing scope when using ng-include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412410/angularjs-losing-scope-when-using-ng-include)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because ng-include creates a new scope, try doing:

```
ng-model="$parent.hasFixed"
```

it should work. but there might be a better solution.

Comment: Yes.. it did work. But can say me what's it actually doing?

Comment: here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude
... it says under the "Directive info" section, the directive creates a new scope. So, you created 2 hasFixed property. One from the parent, the other from the child; but you really wanted to update the parent's.