# AngularJS $scope.value = nulll not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an application which has code like this:

```
<div class="step-tab" id="tab_2" ng-class="{'step--active': step == 2}" ng-controller="eventCatCtrl">
    <div ng-if="step == 2" ng-include="'include/step2.php'"></div>
</div>
```

Inside my step2.php file I have:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="catTitle">Category Title <span>*</span></label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="catTitle" ng-model="catTitle" placeholder="Please enter your Category Title">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="catDes">Category Description</label><textarea name="" class="form-control" id="catDes" placeholder="Enter a description here" ng-model="catDes" id="" cols="10" rows="6"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input ng-click="catValues(catTitle, catDes, $event)" type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Add Category">
</div>
```

I have triggered the function catValues and did:

```
eventApp.controller("eventCatCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.catValues = function(catTitle, catDes, $event){
        $scope.catTitle = null;
        $scope.catDes = null;       
    }
});
```

However the null doesn't work, also a lot of other stuff that I have in that controller and in the functions work perfectly well but only this null doesn't work.

If I include `ng-controller="eventCatCtrl"` inside the `step2.php` file then the null works.

I would just like to know why the null is not clearing values of `catTitle` and `catDes` and why is everything else apart from that working fine.

Comment: Could you do `$scope.$parent.catTitle` ?

Comment: @Zehelvion `$scope.$parent.catTitle = null;` Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because `ng-include` create a separate scope, so in your `id="tab_2"` has `eventCatCtrl`, so the scope of `eventCatCtrl` controller is the parent scope for the scope which create by `ng-include`, So if u try to assign `null` it will check for the scope of `eventCatCtrl` it cannot see the scope of `ng-include`, thats why its not going to assign `null` for `ng-include` models.

Do achieve this in your case u can define the models in `ng-include` template in `eventCatCtrl` like below,

```
eventApp.controller("eventCatCtrl", function($scope){
        $scope.includeData = {}; 
    $scope.catValues = function(catTitle, catDes, $event){
        $scope.includeData.catTitle = null;                // modify this
        $scope.includeData.catDes = null;       
    }
});
```

and change your includes like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="catTitle" ng-model="includeData.catTitle" placeholder="Please enter your Category Title">

<textarea name="" class="form-control" id="catDes" placeholder="Enter a description here" ng-model="includeData.catDes" id="" cols="10" rows="6"></textarea>
```

Comment: So is there a solution to this, some other command that can make that null for me? Or the only way to make it work is to include the `ng-controller` inside `step2.php` file.

Comment: is `catValues ` function execute after click the `button` ?

Comment: Yes it works. I have a lot of stuff in it and all the other stuff works fine.

Comment: Okay it works, other ways of fixing this or maybe a detailed info of what is going on can be seen here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412410/angularjs-losing-scope-when-using-ng-include?rq=1)