# Filtering with search field in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, angular-filters

Search filtering is not working for me in AngularJS.

My navbar.html:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" data-ng-model="searchQuery">
```

In the view template:

```
<ul class="userlist">
  <li class="list" data-ng-repeat="user in users | filter: searchQuery">
    <!--users show here-->
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the index.html:

```
<div data-ng-include data-src="'./templates/navbar.html'"></div>
<div data-ng-view></div>
```

I do not receive any error messages, it just does not work.
Is this because the model is in separate templates?

---

2 hours later and I still have no clue how to implement this.
But I think I am getting closer. When I change the searchQuery string, it filters the results.
So all I need to find out is how I control this string from the navbar template (which is included with ng-include).

The two controllers:

```
//NAVBAR template controller
app.controller('NavbarController', ['$scope', '$location',
    function ($scope, $location) {

    }]);

//LIST page controller
app.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.listpage = {'searchQuery' : ''};

        //...

    }]);
```

view.html:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="user in users | filter: listpage.searchQuery">
```

navbar.html

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="listpage.searchQuery">
```

How do I change the listpage object in the navbar template (which is included with ng-include), so that it is applied in the filter?

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `ng-model`, always try to use indirect references (reference properties of an object on scope rather than a scope property itself). Using

```
ng-model="someObject.searchQuery"
```

will correctly share your data across scope trees, while

```
ng-model="searchQuery"
```

will write only on your local scope and leave the parent unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Ng-include creates new child scope, so searchQuery in parent scope is not updating.

It is hard to give you specific solution because you included only part of your code, but here : [AngularJS - losing scope when using ng-include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412410/angularjs-losing-scope-when-using-ng-include)
you can find good explanations with example solutions.