# Not able to fetch the value while using ng-include?

Tags: angularjs

My **Employee.cshtml**

```
<html ng-app="crudModule">
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<head> 
</head>
<h2>Employee List</h2>
<h2>===================</h2>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="employeeController">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>               
                <td><div ng-include="'/Content/EmployeeInfo/employee.html'"></div></td>
                <td><div ng-include="'/Content/EmployeeInfo/department.html'"></div></td> 
                <td><div ng-include="'/Content/EmployeeInfo/EmployeeDepartmentOperations.html'"></div></td> 
            </tr>
        </table>            
    </div>         
</body>
</html>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MyScripts/Module.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MyScripts/Controllers/ITOps/ITOpsController.js"></script>
```

**EmployeeDepartmentOperations.html**

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>EmployeeId</td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="empID" ng-model="EmployeeId" /></td>           
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" id="txtInsertEmployeeDept" value="Insert Employee & Department" ng-click="InsertEmployeeDepartment()" />
```

And the **controller**

```
app.controller('employeeController', function ($scope, crudService) {  


        $scope.InsertEmployeeDepartment = function () {

            alert($scope.EmployeeId);           
        }   
});
```

But I am not able to get the **$scope.EmployeeId.** *It is coming as undefined*.

Why?What mistake I am doing?

Comment: May be this link about creating a new scope with ng-include helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412410/angularjs-losing-scope-when-using-ng-include

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27309675/2460773

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes both @Alex and @Nitsan pointed me in the right direction. I need to do

```
 ng-model="$parent.EmployeeId"
```

Thanks to both of you.