# AngularJS - trigger same event for included footer and header on all pages

Tags: angularjs, events, scope, include

This question have good chance to be a duplicate, but after some searches I wasn't able to find a good explanation to my problem - so I apologize if this is the case.

Well, I got a template which is actually written like this:

```
<div ng-include="'includes/header.html'"></div>

<section>... Template for homepage, page1, page2... </section>

<div ng-include="'includes/footer.html'"></div>
```

My header.html is like this:

```
<section class="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="#/"><img id="logotype" src="images/logotype.png"></a>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="border-none">
                <a class="a" ng-click="chatClicked = !chatClicked">Click to chat</a>
            </li>
            <li id="logout" class="glyphicon glyphicon-off border-none">
                <a href="#/logout">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

And my footer.html like this:

```
<section class="footer">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul id="menu-left">
            <li>
                <a href="#/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="a" ng-click="chatClicked = !chatClicked">Click to chat</a>
            </li>
    </div>
</section>
```

I was wondering if there is a way to open open/hide this new include on all pages (

```
<div ng-if="chatClicked" ng-controller='ChatController' ng-include="'includes/popup-chat-to-click.html'"></div>
```

) each time the event *chatCliked* is triggered - and if it is possible - where it is the best to place this last div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok problem resolved using this link, sorry:

[AngularJS - losing scope when using ng-include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412410/angularjs-losing-scope-when-using-ng-include)

This was a matter of $scope.

I had to add this in my controller:

```
app.controller('homeController',
        ['$scope'',
            function ($scope) {

                $scope.chat = { clicked: false };
}]);
```

in my main view:

```
<div ng-include="'includes/header.html'"></div>

<div ng-if="chat.clicked" ng-controller='ChatController' ng-include="'modules/chat/popup-contact.html'"></div>
```

in my header.html:

```
<a class="a" ng-click="chat.clicked = !chat.clicked">Contact us</a>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @theDmi: Roger that - answer evolved.