# ngModel doesn't bind to select option

Tags: angularjs

I can't figure out why i can't bind to a select element
there is my code:

```
<select ng-model="site" ng-change="getAll()">
  <option value="SG1">SG1</option>
  <option value="PZ1">PZ1</option>
  <option value="NE1">NE1</option>
</select>
```

getAll() make an alert of 'site' but the var is never updated.
$scope.site is nerver use except in getAll()

```
  $scope.getAll = function () {
    alert($scope.site);
  }
```

If i set $scope.site to a value it is display but never update either

Edit:
I forgot a big detail...
The select is display with a ng-include directive

```
<section id="sectionLeft" ng-include="nav[navId]">

</section>
```

Comment: show the full code

Comment: @Sandroggy , add controller code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-include` creates a new scope which prototypally inherits from your controller. So you are initially reading the selected option from your controller, but when the select element writes a new selected option it ends up writing to the inherited scope.

You can bind to an object instead.

Controller:

```
    $scope.data = { site: "SG1" };
    $scope.getAll = function() {
        alert($scope.data.site);
    }
```

Template:

```
    <select ng-model="data.site" ng-change="getAll()">
        <option value="SG1">SG1</option>
        <option value="PZ1">PZ1</option>
        <option value="NE1">NE1</option>
    </select>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412410/angularjs-losing-scope-when-using-ng-include) for more details.

If you don't like switching to an object, look up `controller as` syntax and bind directly to the controller instead of `$scope`.

Answer (score 0):

I've fiddled your code and i'm able to get the updated value in the alert box.

```
$scope.getAll = function() {
    alert($scope.site);
};
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/12880/)